# Eclipse JEE on linux is not launching after clicking on the eclipse icon from app menu. It is only opening from the installed directory

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, eclipse-jee

I am on kubuntu 21.10. I installed java Openjdk-11 with apt package manager. Then I downloaded the eclipse installer from official website and installed the **JEE Eclipse**(Eclipse for web development).

But the icon that appears in both the desktop and app menu is of **JSE Eclipse**. Clicking on it doesn't launch anything. The only way to launch JEE eclipse is from file manager's installed directory by clicking on the executable eclipse file.

How to get a working icon in the app menu?

Answer (score 0):

I found one simple workaround as I couldn't find the solution to my problem anywhere. It needs a little bit of work but it will save you few clicks from next time while launching the Eclipse from app menu/desktop/dock.

You can directly download the JEE Eclipse [package](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) and extract it in your preferred folder. Or you can download the [installer](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/installer) and install the JEE Eclipse from the GUI too.

After that you need to create a shortcut for the executable eclipse file manually. For this many articles are there which you can follow. I followed this youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1RqybkE9pls) and the shortcut works fine now.